# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'labels' referenced before assignment in PyTorch while doing X-Ray classification

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to replicate [this Kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/debarshichanda/seresnext50-but-with-attention), using my data. I am not posting the whole code here, because it is huge.

Received an error, which cannot fix myself

```
----> 2 model, history = run_fold(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, device=CFG.device, fold=0, num_epochs=CFG.num_epochs)

1 frames
<ipython-input-63-1ac8b53f265b> in train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs, 
dataloaders, dataset_sizes, device, fold)
 23             for inputs, classes in dataloaders[phase]:
 24                 inputs = inputs.to(CFG.device)
---> 25                 labels = labels.to(CFG.device)
 26 
 27                 # forward

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'labels' referenced before assignment
```

My data structure looks the same as the notebook

[image]

I have checked similar questions, [there are several of them](https://www.google.com/search?q=UnboundLocalError%3A%20local%20variable%20%27labels%27%20referenced%20before%20assignment&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS891US891&oq=UnboundLocalError%3A%20local%20variable%20%27labels%27%20referenced%20before%20assignment&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i61j69i58j69i60l2.548j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), but this is more tech question how to fix this thing. Maybe something wrong with index? Appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the `for` loop. It should be `labels` instead of `classes`:

```py
# ...
for inputs, labels in dataloaders[phase]:
    inputs = inputs.to(CFG.device)
    labels = labels.to(CFG.device)
    # ...
```

Comment: You are the best! Thank you so much for your time and efforts!